# Choosing profiles for combined flair

Tags: feature-request, flair, combined-flair

It would be nice if you could pick which profiles to show on your combined flair image. Or to create multiple combined flair images with different associated profiles.

I'm suggesting this because I believe not all SE sites are relevant to each other. I'd like to use a combined flair for SO, Programmers.SE and Code Review, but not other SE sites I'm active on.

Comment: +1, I agree completely!

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128466/id-like-network-flair-to-allow-selection-of-included-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: @gnat this is the older post so the other is duplicate of this one.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd agree

Comment: [Declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297292/152859)

Answer (score 8):

Adapting some answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176140/how-to-remove-area-51-from-my-piece-of-valuable-flair)...

(The easiest thing to do is to just use per-site flair (though of course that does not answer your question).  And advantage of this is that, since someone customizing flair may be tailoring things to impress some audience, there is more to see (and be impressed by).)

For multi-site flair, there are tools to help:

- [StackImage 2 - Create Your Own Unique Custom Flair!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2400/stackimage-2-create-your-own-unique-custom-flair)
- [se-flair: HTML combined Stack Exchange site flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair)

...and then there is the API:

- https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users

(Yes, I realize the question is a feature request (for a method that is *even easier* than the methods listed here), but in some sense the API is an already-present implementation of the feature.  Also, between now and the time an easier method gets implemented (if it does), readers may come looking for something that works *now*.)

Comment: Easy points, lol! :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I keep seeing comments about points being easy to get on Meta anyway, but I don't agree at all...very hard to crack for a new user (sticking to the serious stuff).  ...so it's nice that, yes, *these* ones were easy.  :)

Comment: Over 20% of what you had! Anyway, if **I** reached over 30K (spent 8K on bounties by now) then **anyone** can. :-P

Comment: I'll take the advice, but you *were* in before SE was a finely tuned machine with nothing left to criticize.  :P

Comment: Advice? Where? ;-) Anyway you're right - too bad for you! :D