# Combined flair for more than 7 sites

Tags: discussion, flair, combined-flair

Somewhat related to *[Choosing profiles for combined flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81699/167443)*...

<strike>It appears the combined flair has space for about 7 Stack Exchange sites (I'm estimating, I've only got 4 on there now).</strike>The combined flair can fit 7 different Stack Exchange sites. What happens if a user has more than 200 rep on more sites than the seven sites that fit on the flair? Does the flair

- Use what first went on and ignore anything beyond what fits? (Mine currently seems to be ordered based on how old the profiles are)
- Use the top-repped accounts, and order them by rep? (Mine *may* be doing this, but I can't tell at this time, since rep order and age order are the same)
- Break?
- Randomly select some sites?

Has anyone encountered this before, or is it unusualy to have 200+ rep on that many different Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: No, [it's not unusual](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts) :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are ordered by reputation.

Pick any proposal in the [commitment phase on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) to see for yourself.

Scrolling through the [Graphic Design proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924?phase=commitment), it does not appear to be rare at all to have >200 on more sites than the flair will display.

Comment: It actually can fit 7. [Example](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/31759f6005364343a728045a4e217082.png)

Comment: I stand corrected.