# I'd like combined flair to allow selection of included Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, flair, combined-flair

> **Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing profiles for combined flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81699/choosing-profiles-for-combined-flair)

I love the feature, but I'd like to decide which sites to include, in the same way I can decide which sites to show on my profile on Careers.

Answer (score 4):

I agree. If I, or anybody else, has a blog about a certain topic (to use one example), I'm going to want a flair that only shows certain sites that are related to that topic. If I was blogging about being a webmaster, for example, I would want to show my profiles on webmasters.se, ux.se, and SO, but not meta.so, area51, skeptics.se, etc.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying you even want different flairs for different usage scenarios, like for the site-specific flairs one can choose a color scheme with some URL parameters. I guess that's easier implemented than some user setting. (Of course, then users could create *many* flairs with different combinations of sites, each of them needing [some server processing time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65889/rep-value-on-the-new-flair-is-not-updated/65890#65890), but I guess only a few would.)