# How to remove Area 51 from my piece of valuable flair?

Tags: support, area-51, flair

This is a snapshot of my current piece of valuable flair<sup>tm</sup>:

[image: My flair]

I'd like to add it to my professional website, but I don't like having "Area 51" on the list.  The rest are professional-looking sites.

> **Question**: How to get rid of Area 51 from my piece of valuable flair?

The only solutions I can think of are:

- To request an Area 51 account deletion, but I'd prefer not to do that since I like to participate in Area 51, receive updates about stackexchange sites, and so on.
- To become active on several stackexchange sites, thereby knocking Area 51 off the list.  This seems like an awful lot of work.
- To misbehave at Area 51, thereby receiving downvotes lowering my reputation.  This is obviously a bad idea.

If it were another site, I could just offer some bounties or turn questions to CW to get rid of the reputation, but I don't believe that's possible on Area 51.

Comment: If you think having Area 51 in the flair is bad, I wonder what you think about [my flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/35162.png)...

Comment: @Yannis Hahaha...Programmers SE....I see what you mean

Comment: @Bart I kinda walked into this, didn't I?

Comment: You could request that your area51 is disassociated from your other accounts

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I don't think that's an option anymore. It used to be, but then some change in the login thingy that links accounts together removed it.

Comment: `I don't like having "Area 51" on the list. The rest are professional-looking sites.` -- *Ouch.*

Comment: I'm with @RobertHarvey why so much hate and coldness towards the little green men??

Comment: Aww... I genuinely feel guilty now.  (Let's just say, potential employers will be looking at my website, and I don't want them to misinterpret "Area 51"; the site itself looks professionally designed.)

Comment: Build your own flair using the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users).

Comment: Best.  Gravitar.  Ever.

Comment: @DouglasS.Stones - People put way too much emphasis on what recruiters will think of their Stack Exchange flair. While that may be important here, in the real world you'll find that it just doesn't matter that much.  I meet great developers all the time who don't have a Stack Exchange account, and some recruiters are likely to fall into the mix perhaps even to the point of not even knowing what Stack Exchange is.... Also, I'm not sure recruiters are quite that thorough to where they'll click every single link on your site.

Comment: I'm working on a reimplementation of flair using the Stack Exchange API.

Comment: Isn't it a little ironic for Area 51 to be *too* visible?

Comment: A workaround would be to download your flair and edit it with Paint and then upload it to your personal site, although I admit it would not be practical having to do that regularly.

Answer (score 10):

Your best bet is to use **different accounts** for your personal and professional access.

Disassociating accounts [is no longer possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109054/137004), but you can create a new "personal" account for Area 51 and then ask nicely to have your existing Area 51 activity associated with those credentials instead.

This will be less convenient for you, lots of logging in and out, no notifications about the other account, but that's the price you pay for maintaining separate personas.

The main advantage, apart from being doable right now without waiting on a new feature being implemented, is that this would be **a real separation**.  Changing flair display would just lead to future finer-grained feature requests.  *You* want to choose what flair's displayed, the *next person* will want to hide an account on the account overview page, the next on the full account list, the next will want to hide a specific question that they don't want people to see, the list goes on and on.

In the same way that you probably have personal and work email addresses, if you want separate SE personas... **use separate SE accounts**.

Comment: +1 for a solution, but I honestly think that this is overkill for the problem at hand. Creating a separate account just to change what shows up on your flair seems more work than it is worth :(

Answer (score 7):

Right now we don't have a way to customize the network flair. The best you could do right now is to use the site-specific flair. For example, here's mine for MSO:

[image: flair!]

These are accessible via the "flair" link from your user profile on every site.

Comment: Any plans to have a way to customize the network flair?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There's [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81699/choosing-profiles-for-combined-flair), and I personally think this would be nice to have, but it isn't on anybody's list to implement right now far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, I already spent 2 bounties there so well aware of that. But as community manager can't you convince the big bosses of its importance? ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd There are other things I want more first myself. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, there is not much to answer here. You have outlined your options. But the whole premise of Area51 being unprofessional is flawed.

> I'd like to add it to my professional website, but I don't like having "Area 51" on the list. The rest are professional-looking sites.

I don't know who would ever hold Area51 participation against you when it comes to professionalism. And especially if your active participation there leads to new sites being created within the network, providing a platform for professionals or hobbyists to ask high quality questions and seeing them answered. Given the effort involved, if that does not show professionalism, I don't know what does.

I would happily defend my position if anyone from outside the SE network were to argue otherwise. And if that determined their opinion of my professionalism, I'm not so sure I would value their opinion all that much.

If you behave in a professional manner on Area51, there is no reason whatsoever to hide it anywhere.

Comment: While I don't disagree with anything you've said, I think the general form of the question has merit.  If a developer wants to show their flair as part of a CV-style website, for example, then listing the gaming and cooking sites isn't necessarily useful.  There would be some value in user-customisable flair to assist with this!

Comment: @DanPuzey Then again, your flair would link back to your general SE account still showing your participation. Those who are bothered by so-called "unprofessional" sites, will figure that out as well. And even the gaming or cooking sites I would not regard as unprofessional. If you really don't want those to be linked to your participation on other sites, two separate accounts are still an option. That said, SE sites are not forums. They are quality sites with quality content. Whether the application is in a hobby domain or not. I'd proudly show any of them.

Comment: I understand that *you* are proud of your flair.  I personally don't share mine; I have no vested interest.  But I can see that some might want to keep professional and personal profiles a little more separate.  For example: if my reputation for cooking were better than for programming, it would seem reasonable to *not* highlight that on the front page of my CV site.  Yes, you'd still be able to drill down, but the first view could be considered better.  *You* may not want this feature, but forcing your preference on others with a "Get over it" non-answer seems a little harsh.

Comment: @DanPuzey First, it's not a feature request. It's a support question. The OP outlined what the possible answers could be, leaving the assumption that Area51 is unprofessional when it distinctly is not. Second, nothing is stopping you from separating between professional sites and those you don't regard as being professional. If you don't want to associate it with your account, don't associate it. And then again we're all basing this on the assumption that the viewer will know what those little icons are. And if they do, they sure know where to look for a bit more information.

Comment: You're right, it's not a feature request, it's a request for assistance, and your response was "your request isn't valid; get over it."  I personally think that's not a helpful response, even if the ultimate answer is that the request can't be satisfied.

Comment: @DanPuzey My answer was "You've answered your own support request, but your premise is flawed". But if you distinctly feel my answer is unhelpful or in fact not an answer, feel free to vote/flag accordingly. That said, I have changed the wording to address your concerns regarding those.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is currently no way to control what comes up on your valuable flair :(

If I were you I would **download the image and edit it to remove the area 51 logo**. Upload the edited valuable flair to your website, instead of linking right to the provided image. Then do that once every month or so to keep your valuable flair fairly up to date.

Creating multiple accounts just to avoid this issue seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 3):

I found a few Stack Apps that can help you with this:

**StackImage**
[StackImage - Generating Images of Questions and Users [Now with Global Flair!]](https://stackapps.com/questions/847/stackimage-generating-images-of-questions-and-users-now-with-global-flair)

**StackImage 2**
[StackImage 2 - Create Your Own Unique Custom Flair!](https://stackapps.com/questions/2400/stackimage-2-create-your-own-unique-custom-flair?lq=1)

**SE-Flair** [se-flair: HTML combined Stack Exchange site flair](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair)

**Edit:** The third stack app (se-flair) seems to work well. It will give you your flair in a code output instead of an image. After embedding it in your site, you can remove the icon(s) you don't want with your own Javascript or CSS.

Comment: Thanks for this, but the "global flair" doesn't seem to work for me.  I put in my email address (hopefully I don't receive spam as a result) and it outputs an image saying "Invalid GUID Specified".

Comment: Yeah I got the same issue. Weird stuff. Perhaps you could get in touch with the guy who maintains it.

Comment: I found another solution for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always build your own flair using the SE API?

Comment: Ah, I only read through the answers, not the comments.

Comment: No worries, since this *is* an answer.  (Also, future readers may follow the same reading pattern you did.)