# Combined flair (not network flair)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flair, combined-flair

At present, there are two options for flairs.

Either the site-specific flair (*or*) the network flair.

That is, if I choose it from Stack Overflow, I can either use this:

[image]

Or I can use this:

[image]

So *my* feature request is **Can we have a flair containing only** ***selected*** **sites?**

That is, if I want to only include Stack Overflow and Travel.se, then I may put something like this

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2824081.png?theme=clean&site=stackoverflow&site=travel
```

#### Another Case

If I want to show only Android SE and Meta SE, I can use

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2824081.png?theme=clean&site=android&site=meta.se
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd really like to customize flair that finely, you'll need to utilize the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com) and construct it yourself.

Adding options to a URL like that opens up a huge potential for abuse where users could chew up a lot of our resources creating flair images by just sending a flood of requests with differing options. Sure, flair images are cached for quite a while, but given the number of users and number of sites, it's easy to keep coming up with new ones that need generated. On-the-fly options like this just aren't doable.

Comment: Care to decline the duplicate feature request, posted over 6 years ago? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard `[tag:status-abandoned]` or `[tag:status-aged-away]` :)